# Auto Slide image in Android

Tags: android

Im trying to write a very basic android app that displays around 5 pictures one after each other on the screen. I want it to display a different picture after about 10 seconds. Can anyone advise me on how I would go around this. Below i have outlined what i would be looking for.

Picture 1

Picture 2

Picture 3

Picture 4

Picture 5

display full screen Picture 1
wait 10 seconds
Remove Picture 1 and Display Picture 2
Wait 10 seconds
Remove Picture 2 and Display Picture 3
Wait 10 seconds
Remove Picture 3 and Display Picture 4
Wait 10 seconds
Remove Picture 4 and Display Picture 5
Wait 10 seconds

Start again...thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Where exactly is your problem? Please show us what you have done so far.

Comment: i am making a app that show image one by one after every 10 sec automaticaly..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use View flipper to slide your images and  to do same automatically at some interval,use TimerTask along with View Flipper.

Inside TimerTask, use Viewflipper.showNext();

Have a look at this [post](http://iamvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2012/07/android-timertask.html).

Also have a look at startFlipping() and setFlipInterval() methods in ViewFlipper class

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/03/auto-flipping-of-viewflipper.html

http://javatechig.com/android/android-viewflipper-example

You can ask if you have any further queries..

Answer (score 16):

You can use viewflipper for this:

view_flipper.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/viewflipper"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoStart="true"
    android:flipInterval="2000" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/picture1" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/picture2" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/picture3" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/picture4" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/picture5" />
</ViewFlipper>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Mention this xml file in onCreate of your mainActivity. Like:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_flipper);
}
```

Thats it. After loading layout it will automatically start animating because we mention autoStart:true in xml.

Comment: thank you sir...but i am new in android so please if you send me whole code.then please reply.

Comment: thanks allot sir. actually i want make a app in which i want first play some image after that play a video again play image,means that i want schedule image and video both after 10 sec play one by one.